# Tornado - getting return value from IOLoop.add_callback()

Tags: tornado

I'm not sure what the difference is between the following two functions:

```
 IOLoop.add_callback(callback, *args, **kwargs)
```

AND

```
IOLoop.spawn_callback(callback, *args, **kwargs)
```

I did read the documentation however didn't really understand what `stack_context` is. It seems like a way to preserve variables between calls to other threads but not sure. Since the `spawn_callback` doesn't use the `stack_context` does this mean exceptions will not be passed back to the caller?

Either way I know I need to use one of these to call a coroutine method within a non-coroutine method. However I'm unsure how to get the return value using any of these methods. I need to asynchronously call the `httpClient.fetch()` within the `on_message()` within a `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a return value, at least not in the way you're thinking of. Your callback can't even run until the function that called `spawn_callback` (i.e. `on_message`) returns. Just do whatever you want to do when that callback finishes in the callback itself (or pass it another callback to invoke with its result).

`stack_context` is an error-handling mechanism for callback-oriented code. It doesn't let you handle exceptions in the calling function, but it does let you establish an error handler in the calling function that will "follow" the code even through a chain of multiple `add_callback` calls. This turned out to be confusing as often as it helped, so now that coroutines are available I recommend using coroutines as much as possible and when you do need to fall back to raw callbacks, use `spawn_callback` instead of `add_callback` and put your try/except handler in the callback itself.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So if i'm using a coroutine you're saying it's better to use add_callback? Also do you foresee an issue with passing self (WebSocketHandler object) to to the coroutine (potentially down two layers of add_callback() and calling the write_message() within those coroutines?

Comment: No, I'd recommend spawn_callback with coroutines and add_callback if you're avoiding coroutines and doing everything with manual callbacks. It's fine to pass `self` into the callbacks.

Comment: Thanks again Ben. Cheers

Comment: Ben, one more thing within the coroutine function that's spawned I'm allowed to yield other coroutines as normal right (as below)? The code works however  I'm asking because I'm not sure I need to use the fetch with a callback instead for this...               `@tornado.gen.coroutine
   def run(self,url):
      
      httpClient=AsyncHTTPClient()
      
      res= yield httpClient.fetch(x)`

Comment: Yeah, once you're in a coroutine you can use `yield`.